# De-Reference Null Object

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, error

I am reusing some old code here - i've made slight changes but the code itslef is so old it contained the test class within the main class. I have seperated them out but I am getting a pile of errors - any idea on how to get rid of the above erorr message would be appreciated

```
@isTest
public class tester{
 static testMethod void Product_Search_Controller2() {

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Silver Lined Solutions';
        insert(acc);

        Product2 p = new Product2();
        p.Name = 'TestProd';
        p.IsActive = true;
        p.Business_Unit__c = 'MAG';
        insert(p);

        List<PriceBook2> pbs = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Name = 'MA&G' LIMIT 1];
        if(0==pbs.size()) {
            PriceBook2 pbMAG = new PriceBook2();
            pbMAG.Name = 'MA&G';
            pbMAG.IsActive = true;
            insert(pbMAG);
        }

       // PriceBook2 standardPB = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE IsStandard = True LIMIT 1];

       Pricebook2 standardPB = null;
       List <Pricebook2> pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE IsStandard = True LIMIT 1];
       if (pbe.size()>0)
       {
        standardPB = pbe.get(0);

       }

       PriceBookEntry pbe1 = new PriceBookEntry();
     //  if (new PriceBookEntry.Id != null)
       pbe1.PriceBook2Id = standardPB.Id;
       pbe1.Product2Id = p.Id;
       pbe1.IsActive = true;
       pbe1.UnitPrice=10;

      insert(pbe1);








       pbe1 = new PriceBookEntry();
        pbe1.PriceBook2Id = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE Name = 'MA&G' LIMIT 1].Id;
        pbe1.Product2Id = p.Id;
        pbe1.IsActive = true;
        pbe1.UnitPrice=100;
        insert(pbe1);

        RecordType rt = null;
        List<RecordType> rts = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Opportunity' AND Name='MA&G Corporate' LIMIT 1];
        if(0==rts.size()) {
            rts = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Opportunity' AND IsActive=True LIMIT 1];
        }
        rt = rts.get(0);

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'TestOpp';
        opp.CloseDate = date.today();
        opp.StageName = 'Anything';
        opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        opp.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
        opp.PriceBook2Id = pbe1.PriceBook2Id;
        insert(opp);

        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.Product_Search);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('OppId',opp.Id);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('OppPB',opp.PriceBook2Id);

        Product_Search_Controller psc  = new Product_Search_Controller();

        system.assertequals(opp.Id, psc.opportunityId);
        system.assertequals(opp.PriceBook2Id, psc.oppPB);

        system.assert(psc.getBUList().size()>0);

        psc.BU = 'MAG';
        psc.searchQuery = 'TestProd';
        psc.Search();
        system.assert(psc.getHasResults());
        system.assert(psc.pbes.size()>0);

        psc.selectedPBEId = psc.pbes.get(0).Id;

        psc.ShowAll();
        system.assert(psc.getHasResults());

        PageReference oppProdMgr = psc.selectPBE();
        system.assertequals(opp.Id, oppProdMgr.getParameters().get('Id'));
        system.assertequals(psc.selectedPBEId, oppProdMgr.getParameters().get('addProdPBE'));

        psc.searchQuery = 'A';
        psc.Search();

        psc.cancel();

    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring at?

Comment: line 35 column 1

Comment: @user6866 fyi, line numbers don't show up in sfse posts, it's more useful if you post the specific error message, than flag the line with a comment e.g. `// error occurs here`. Makes it easier for people to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new PricebookEntry at line 25:

```
 Pricebook2 standardPB = null;
```

You then query for & assign to standardPB another PBE:

```
List <Pricebook2> pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE IsStandard = True LIMIT 1];
   if (pbe.size()>0)
   {
    standardPB = pbe.get(0);

   }
```

However, if no PBE is returned from your query, standardPB remains null, hence your error at line 35 when it is referenced:

```
pbe1.PriceBook2Id = standardPB.Id;
```

You will need to set SeeAllData to true to access Pricebooks: [SeeAllData=false and Pricebooks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11058/seealldata-false-and-pricebooks) although the newly added Test.getStandardPricebookId() method may work in your case: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_getStandardPricebookId

Answer (score 0):

I am betting that you are in or testing in an org that has not made the Standard Pricebook active.

You code

```
Pricebook2 standardPB = null;
       List <Pricebook2> pbe = [SELECT Id FROM PriceBook2 WHERE IsStandard = True LIMIT 1];
       if (pbe.size()>0)
       {
        standardPB = pbe.get(0);

       }

       PriceBookEntry pbe1 = new PriceBookEntry();
     //  if (new PriceBookEntry.Id != null)
       **pbe1.PriceBook2Id = standardPB.Id;**
       pbe1.Product2Id = p.Id;
       pbe1.IsActive = true;
       pbe1.UnitPrice=10;
```

Does not test if it actually found a standard price book where I indicated. So if it does not exist you will get a dereference